# Multipath routing doesn't work

Tags: linux, networking, router, vpn, routing

What I am trying to achieve: I have a server, which is gateway for client connected via VPN (WireGuard) to it. Server itself connected to 4 another server via VPN (WireGuard) and I want route all incoming traffic via those 4 another server with load balancing. I know there is multipath routing in linux but it doesn't work in my case for some reason.

What I have:

- ubuntu server
- wg0 net interface, where all incoming traffic comes from. Server itself has ip 192.168.155.1.
- wg1 net interface, where all 4 another server connect. Server itself has ip 192.168.166.1, and another servers have ips 192.168.166.10-14.
- I have this routing rule: `32763: from 192.168.155.0/24 lookup 120`
- I have these routes:

```
default
    nexthop via 192.168.166.10 dev wg1 weight 1
    nexthop via 192.168.166.11 dev wg1 weight 1
    nexthop via 192.168.166.12 dev wg1 weight 1
    nexthop via 192.168.166.13 dev wg1 weight 1
```

I don't know why, but all traffic goes throw 192.168.166.11. How to make routing to forward traffic randomly via 192.168.166.10-14?

Comment: What kind of traffic? TCP or UDP? One TCP connection or multiple? Same destination IP or different?

Comment: How do you determine that no multipathing is happening? One TCP connection wouldn't be multipathed for example.

Comment: @user1686 mostly TCP. Multiple connections. Different dest IP.

Comment: @mtak  I have several connections, with different dest ip. I determine it by monitoring network trafic on 192.168.166.[10-13] hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So I've re-read the post a bit more carefully...*

Selecting a specific nexthop using `via` only works with interfaces that support link-layer (L2) addressing, which WireGuard tunnels **don't have**, so the result is normal.

On a traditional Ethernet interface, routing packets `via 192.168.166.10` is done by sending them to the *MAC address* of the specified 192.168.166.10  nexthop – i.e. the IP (L3) header doesn't change when routing, only the lower layer header does.

But "L3 tunnel" interfaces such as WireGuard, PPP or GRE don't have any way for the IP layer to specify which node a packet should be directed at, which means *all* your nexthops are basically equivalent to `nexthop dev wg1`.

(In WireGuard, when you have multiple peers per interface, your "AllowedIPs" setting decides which peer should receive which packets based on the destination IP address – it's almost like a routing table but hidden inside WireGuard and not integrated in any way with the real Linux routing table.)

Your options are to use separate WireGuard tunnel interfaces (one per nexthop) or to switch to a L2 tunnel (such as EoIP, ZeroTier, OpenVPN in 'tap' mode, or maybe VXLAN).